# Convert 2D short array to Base64

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 2D short array coming from a C++ library. The array contains the pixels of a 16 bit grayscale image. I am trying to convert it to Base64 to display it. My C# code is as follows:

```cs
string picture_path = "~/Picture/CT_Axial_Z/CT_Axial-Z_0111.png";
string path = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath(picture_path);
    
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    IntPtr gpget = Open16BitGrayImage(path);
    CImage_DLL gget = (CImage_DLL)Marshal.PtrToStructure(gpget, typeof(CImage_DLL));
    int short_size = sizeof(short);
    int p_s_cursor = 0;
    
    Array pshImageData = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(short), gget.m_nH, gget.m_nW);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < gget.m_nH; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gget.m_nW; j++)
        {
            short data = (short)Marshal.PtrToStructure(gget.pshImageData + p_s_cursor, typeof(short));
            pshImageData.SetValue(data, i, j);
            p_s_cursor += short_size;
        }
    }
}
```

I need to convert it to Base64 and display it on a canvas. How should I do it?

Comment: I think you mean that you need to convert the Base64 string that you receive to bytes.  The bytes are then used to create the image.  Try :  byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String(string)

Comment: No, I mean convert the int 2D array of "pshImageData" to base64,but still thank you!